# android project backup

Tags: android

is there any chance for take android project backups by running script file. rather every time copy and paste

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered to use a version control system?

I recommend you have a in depth look at GIT - which can also be used **offline** and is perfect for backup that way: http://git-scm.com/

Comment: thankq for your reply but i want to take become by running script file i heared some where by using ant we can keep total project source in destination folder with current time